# Rails ActiveModel::Serializer nest response in "data": parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have a rails app in which I use the gem `active_model_serializers`. In my responses I would like to nest my results inside a `"data":` parent. Currently when I don't get any data for a response I get the following JSON:

```
[]
```

What I want is something like this:

```
{
  "data": []
}
```

I would also like to use the same format in cases where I have data, like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 135,
      [...]
```

I've managed to get the structure I want by using `render json`, like this:

```
render json: { data: respond_values}
```

But in this case my serialiser gets ignored and all the attributes in my model gets returned. My serialiser looks like this:

```
class TranslationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :value, :created_at, :updated_at, :language_id
  has_one :language
  has_one :localized_string, serializer: LocalizedStringParentSerializer
end
```

If I instead use `respond_with` my serialiser works but I don't get the structure I want - the data parent / container is missing.

Any ideas on what I need to to to get my serialiser to work properly?

Comment: Try: `render json: respond_values, each_serializer: TranslationSerializer, root: 'data'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off unless you need to support a legacy API use the [JSON:API](http://jsonapi.org/) adapter:

> By default ActiveModelSerializers will use the Attributes Adapter (no
>   JSON root). But we strongly advise you to use JsonApi Adapter, which
>   follows 1.0 of the format specified in jsonapi.org/format.

While nobody fully agrees with all the design decisions in JSON:API it is widely supported by front-end frameworks such as Ember and Angular and is likely to gain further traction.

Otherwise you would need to create your own adapter since the JSON adapter does not allow you to set the root key.

```
# lib/active_model_serializers/adapters/bikeshed_adapter.rb
module ActiveModelSerializers
  module Adapters
    class BikeshedAdapter < Json 
      def root
        :data
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :bikeshed
```

Comment: Thanks,  I've tried to to use the build in `json_api` adapter, but I couldn't get it to work (https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/adapters.md). I created a initializer like this: `initializers/active_model_serializers.rb` with `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you try restarting your server? Initialization files are read when the server starts.

Comment: Yes, I did. But it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: The only thing I did was to add the initializer though. Have I missed something?

Comment: No you should not need to do anything besides adding setting `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter`. Is your initializer in `/config/initializers`? Try adding a log statement `Rails.logger.info "Setting ActiveModelSerializers to use json_api adapter."` to your initializer to ensure that is is being run.

Comment: To clarify, this is how the result still looks: ```[
  {
    "id": 135,
    "value": "Logga in",
    "created_at": "2016-05-29T10:21:57.321Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-29T10:21:57.321Z",
    "language_id": 1,```

Comment: The good ol' trick of restarting my computer seem to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

For any reason, Rails is not finding a Serializer which matches to the model. Maybe something is missing in the convention name/namespace of your model with serializer.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/rendering.md

But, if you explicit declare the serializer, it should work.

```
  render json: @post, serializer: PostPreviewSerializer
```